# HTTP Proxy behavior for X-Forwarded-Host header

Tags: http, http-proxy, forwarding

I have a question regarding how HTTP Proxies usually handle the "X-Forwarded-Host" header. Consider the following scenario where a client sends a HTTP request through a chain of proxies:

```
Client -> Proxy 1 (http://proxy1.com) -> Proxy 2 (http://proxy2.com) -> Server (http://server.com)
```

Proxy 1 sets the "X-Forwarded-Host" header to its own endpoint:

```
X-Forwarded-Host: proxy1.com
```

What behavior is expected from the second proxy? Does it replace the header and again use its own endpoint as the value (proxy2.com), or is it supposed to detect that a "X-Forwarded-Host" header is already present in the request and simply forward this header? Reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host:

> The X-Forwarded-Host (XFH) header is a de-facto standard header for identifying the original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header.

I suspect it is the latter (simply forward the existing header), but I am not sure if this assumption is correct. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Proxy2 is expected to pass the header unchanged. After all it is supposed to be the client's original Host header.

Comment: OK, so as I have expected. But do you or anyone else know if this is also how real proxy applications behave? Or can I expect that e.g. half of them just throw away my X-Forwarded-Host header?

Comment: Real servers can do whatever they want. It is impossible to answer that question. I've never had any interest in this header, so I can't even tell from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

A proxy can replace, ignore or append values to any of the `X-Forwarded-*` headers.

In your case, either

```
X-Forwarded-Host: proxy1.com
X-Forwarded-Host: proxy1.com, proxy2.com
X-Forwarded-Host: proxy2.com
```

are possible outcomes.

Note clients can forge this value in the original request, or can be using some proxies beyond your control that set a value, so if your proxy chain does not append or overwrite that header you might receive

```
X-Forwarded-Host: a-forged-domain
```

If that value is to be trusted, e.g. to activate a feature set in the web application, one must be very sure about the behavior of the proxies in your control. If you get it wrong, bad things will happen:

- https://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/11/anatomy-of-attack-how-i-hacked.html
- https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/middleware/proxy_fix/

E.g:

- proxy1 appends, proxy2 appends: you can receive `X-Forwarded-Host: a-forged-domain, proxy1.com, proxy2.com` so you should trust exactly 2 values.
- proxy1 appends, proxy2 forwards: you can receive `X-Forwarded-Host: a-forged-domain, proxy1.com` so you should trust exactly 1 value.
- proxy1 forwards, proxy2 forwards: you can receive `X-Forwarded-Host: a-forged-domain` so you should trust no values at all.
- proxy1 rewrites, proxy2 forwards: you would only receive `X-Forwarded-Host: proxy1.com` so you could trust that.